# Issue on mac OS with callto or tel

Tags: html

I'm using tel: or callto: in my website but it is not works on mac OS

We write the code in my website

```
<a href="tel: +1(xxx) xxxx-xxx" class="abc">Call me</a>
```

This is working on windows but its not working for mac OS

Comment: Please define "not working". What happens, what do you expect to happen? e.g. "I expect the user to be prompted to open FaceTime, but what happens is..."

Comment: When I clicking on "Call Me" on windows then a pop up is open and says 'open pic an App?' but in mac OS don't open popup. I mean not happen any thing

Comment: Also, which browser, and did you try others? (I just tested your code on Chrome, and it does what I said above: prompted me to open in FaceTime).